# aspnetboilerplate custom validation throws exception

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using [aspnetboilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com) framework in a .Net Core project. I have a custom validation for my view model following on [official documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Validating-Data-Transfer-Objects).

First I have a simple view model with custom validation:

```
    public class EditPropertyViewModel : ICustomValidate
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public long? ParentId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public void AddValidationErrors(CustomValidationContext context)
        {
            if (Id == ParentId)
                context.Results.Add(new ValidationResult("Property cannot be parent of itself!", new [] { "ParentId" } ));
        }    
    }
```

Then my controller is like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditPropertyViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                /* Update property here and return */
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

But when I run the project, this exception occures:

> AbpValidationException: Method arguments are not valid! See ValidationErrors for details.

That means my custom validation has been executed before ModelState.IsValid and there is no chance to handle that exception and show a user friendly message to the user. Disabling validation by [DisableValidation] skips this exception but my validation logic is skipped too. I also tryed to use .NET's standard IValidatableObject interface instead of the abp's ICustomValidate but this not helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: That's how validation works.

Comment: No, validation should not throw an exception. It should add error messages to the ModelState. There is no way to handle this exception now

Comment: Read the documentation that you linked.

Comment: I've read it. Someone else has this problem which not solved. see here: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=8591

Comment: That is solved.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I suppose 'ICustomValidate'  is called once the DTO is initialised and this is why you're getting an exception just before the action is called. According to its [document] (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Validating-Data-Transfer-Objects), *ICustomValidate * interface is designed to validate application service input DTOs and using it to validate action parameters causes this issue. You need to remove this and try to use other validation libraries such as FluentValidation or write your own validation method.